# How to fix Incorrect string value when trying to convert from Latin1 to UTF8 error in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Some of my mysql database tables have been accidentally created as latin1 instead of utf8. I am now trying to fix the issue by changing the columns to their binary type then converting them to utf8 then changing them back to their original type. The problem is I am getting the following error when I try to do this:

```
ERROR 1366 (HY000) at line 524: Incorrect string value: '\xB4s whi...' for column 'sName' at row 73
```

How can I keep this from happening and convert my columns/tables to utf8?

Comment: please add in how you do the collate conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\xB4 is the "acute accent" character in the Latin1 codepage, and must be re-encoded as a 2-byte character in UTF-8.  What you want to do is alter the encoding WITHOUT changing to binary first. This will let the server re-encode the characters correctly.